# How to prevent the tracker from disappearing under other elements?

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

If I want to take a look at data close to the top-border of the plot view, the tracker disappears behind another element. Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

I already looked at the oxyplot documentation and visited several websites. This question has been asked before, but was never answered.

All I expect is that the tracker is fully visible.

[image: Screenshot showing the issue]

Comment: A screenshot would have been helpful here

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have enough reputation to do so... But here's a link with a screenshot: https://ibb.co/6PMjrSH. It shows how my tracker is disappearing underneath a group box outside of the plot view. So for it to be "fully" visible it would have to be underneath the line series.

Comment: Grammar Edit: It would of course have to be below the line series not underneath it!

Comment: Is the control, which overlaps the tracker, somehow loaded after the graph has been loaded ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the plot is loaded after the other control. I also already tried working with `BringToFront();` and `SendToBack();`. But the tracker somehow still behaves in the same way.

Comment: Most likely is not hiding behind anything, add some [margin to your plot](https://imgur.com/hFLp7TV).

Comment: Even after adding some margin to the plot, the tracker still seems to disappear behind the group box. I also tried a combination of `BringToFront();` / `SendToBack();` and using margin. I will now try to create my own tracker via `plotView.ShowTracker(TrackerHitResult HitResult)`. This is pretty tough as there is barely any information regarding this subject. I will provide a solution as soon as I've found one. Meanwhile I will appreciate any ideas / answers!

Comment: If you did then show your code...:O) There might be more than one situation where this happens, we just showed you one, with no group box or anything else to hide the tracker...:O) If you remove the group box, does the problem go away?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem ?

Comment: No, I tried editing several position properties of the TrackerHitResult. But the tracker became really buggy...